# Spring CORS 404

Tags: java, spring-mvc, cors

I'm using spring mvc without spring security.  I have this bean in my `@Configuration` class trying to allow requests from localhost:8080

```
@Bean
    @Profile("dev")
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080").allowedMethods("GET","POST","PUT","DELETE", "OPTIONS");
            }
        };
    }
```

The active profile is dev in my application.yml.  My application is running on localhost:8090.  This request works
http://localhost:8090/assessment/api/questions/page?offset=0&limit=10
but this request returns a 404
http://localhost:8080/assessment/api/questions/page?offset=0&limit=10

Am I missing some extra configuration?

Comment: if you're running the app on port 8090, the API wouldn't be accessible on port 8080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing URL to which to send the request and URL from which the request was sent.

"My application is running on localhost:8090." appears to indicate that the only listener you have is on port 8090.

CORS is a means to allow requests that source from a different domain,
it is not a means to setup multiple listeners in your container.

Comment: Thanks, I'm serving my frontend from a dev server which is on 8080 so I just configured the dev server to change the 8080 to 8090 when sending api requests to my backend